# PHP form handling for dynamically added input fields

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

I am having trouble with the PHP form handling for dynamically added input fields.

The JavaScript and HTML code I am testing with can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/wd5y9/. This part, obviously, works like a charm.

Here is my PHP code -

```
$emailSubject = 'Test Form';
$mailto = 'xxx@xxx.com';

$project = $_POST['project'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
$task = $_POST['task'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$date = date('l F j, Y g:ia T');

$body = <<<EOD

<h2>Form Information</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Project</strong>: $project<br /></td>
<td><strong>Department</strong>: $department<br /></td>
<td><strong>Task</strong>: $task<br /></td>
<td><strong>Hours</strong>: $hours<br /></td>
<td><strong>Comment</strong>: $comment<br /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>Form submitted $date.</p>

EOD;

$headers = "From: xxx@xxx.com\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Here is how the e-mail came through after testing -

Form Information
Project: Array
    Department: Array
    Task: Array
    Hours: Array
    Comment: Array

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have arrays posted. So you need to do something like

```
$project = $_POST['project']['somethingHere'];
```

If you post a print_r of your $_POST (`print_r($_POST)`) we will be able to help you even more.

**EDIT**

From your comment I see that you have two projects, departments, comments etc.

So in order for your code to work it should be a loop.

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($_POST['project']); $i++)
{
 <h2>Form Information</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Project</strong>: $project[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Department</strong>: $department[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Task</strong>: $task[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Hours</strong>: $hours[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Comment</strong>: $comment[$i]<br /></td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: Okay, here is what the print_r returned:

Array ( [project] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [department] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [task] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [hours] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) [comment] => Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 ) [submit] => submit form )

Comment: Adding `for($i=0; $i<=count($POST['project']); $i++)` results in the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ... on line 23. Maybe I copied it wrong?

Comment: @Jennifer my bad forgot the _ in $_POST. Try it out again please.

Comment: It's still kicking out the same error. Here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/6A97f1. Thanks!

Comment: Ι made some changes and now it seems to be working (only notices) Please check it out at http://codepad.viper-7.com/tfEpaF

Comment: No parse error (yay!).  However, the data from the inpute fields are coming through blank. Here is how the e-mail came through after testing - Form Information Project: Department: Task: Hours: Comment:

Comment: from your first comment [project] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )...  it sees that indeed they are coming empty. But it doesn't have anything to do with the code I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple rows (assuming they generate them) posting to your server with the same name, so the values are actually arrays of those values.

So to access the first project, you'd just access the first value of the $project array:

```
$project = $_POST['project'];
$firstProject = $project[0];
```

Or better yet, just loop over them all to spit out all rows in your email, something like this:

```
foreach ($project as $i => $thisProject) {
?>

<h2>Form Information</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Project</strong>: $project[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Department</strong>: $department[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Task</strong>: $task[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Hours</strong>: $hours[$i]<br /></td>
<td><strong>Comment</strong>: $comment[$i]<br /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php }
```